# Mostrar por pantalla los turnos

Tags: php, sql, condiciones

estoy con un problemita de codigo y neceisto algo de ayuda, saben que estoy en un proyecto de una agenda de turnos, el tema es que en esa agenda necesito que se ingresen varios turnos a una misma hora y es que el programa si ingresa varios turnos pero al mostrarlos por pantalla me quedan uno arriba del otro, por eso si me pueden ayudar a que no quede ensima del otro sino que abajo, me seria de mucha ayuda.

por aqui les paso el codigo del ingreso, les paso la parte del php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ves la imagen el turno que se ingresa sea a la misma hora tiene que aparecer abajo de ese

```
   if (isset($_POST['Turno'])) {
include 'model/conexion.php';

$cedula = $_POST['Paciente_turno'];
$sucursal = $_POST['Sucursal_turno'];
$paciente = $_POST['Paciente_turno'];
$usuario = $_POST['Usuario_truno'];

$hora_ini = $_POST['Hora_Inicial'];
$hora_fin = $_POST['Hora_Final'];
$trata = $_POST['Tratamiento'];
$zona = $_POST['Zona'];
$equipo = $_POST['Equipo'];
$fecha = $_POST['Fecha'];
$coment = $_POST['Comentario'];


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM turnos WHERE  FECHA = ' $fecha ' AND NOMBRE_SUCURSAL = 
    '$sucursal'";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

if ($query->rowCount() > 4) {
?>
  <div class="alert">
    <span><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    ERROR: Existe un turno ya registrado en esos horarios, turno NO registrado.
  </div>
<?php
} else {

  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO turnos(FECHA,DATOS_PACIENTE,CEDULA_PACIENTE,NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,PROFESIONAL,HORA_INICIO,HORA_FINAL,TRATAMIENTO,EQUIPO,ZONA,COMENTARIOS) VALUES ('$fecha','$paciente','$cedula','$sucursal','$usuario','$hora_ini','$hora_fin','$trata','$equipo','$zona','$coment')";
  $consulta = $con->prepare($sql1);
  $consulta->execute();


?>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("form1").submit();
      delay(100);
    }
  </script>
  <div class="alert-success">
    <span><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    Turno creado con exito!
  </div>
```

Codigo de horas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ese codigo traigo los metodos POST y luego los agrega con un INSERT, ahora bien si es necesario algun otro codigo que me falte me avisan por algun comentario, yo se los paso.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: dale ya voy, ya te paso

Comment: ahi te pase una foto donde se muestra el turno en pantalla

Comment: Lo que quiero es que se puedan ingresar varios turnos a esas horas osea que tenga 1 turno de 8:00 a 8:30 y otro que tenga 8:00 a 8:30 pero con fiderentes categorias

Comment: nononono espera , me referia a las palabras que van abajo del nombre a esas categorias no tiene nada que ver bro. El tema es que quiero crear varios turnos y que se muestren y que no importe las horas.

Comment: ahora mismo me ingresa en la base de datos con las mismas horas pero cuando se muestra no aparecen porque como ya ahi un turno con esas horas solo muestra uno por eso lo que quiero es que se muestre aunque tengan las mismas horas

Comment: Bueno, segun me parece ver, el problema lo tienes en que no recorres $turnosFiltrados, sino que tan solo escoges el primer elemento con `$dato = current($turnosFiltrados);` dejando de lado si hay más de uno. En ese punto yo pondria un `foreach ($turnosFiltrados as $dato) {` quitando lo del `current`, y lo cerraria antes del final del condicional donde esta dentro (que no tengo nada claro donde es, creo que no esta pegado o no parece tener continuidad entre tus capturas), y a ver que sucede.

Comment: el problema creo entenderlo ahora, pero lo que NO tengo es el código completo, y las capturas son de muy mal ver y trabajar, pero vamos, que ya creo que he localizado al menos parte del problema,  que seria el current ese, si es que $turnosFiltrados contiene todos los datos que realmente necesitas mostrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema, aunque solo se muestra en una imagen de captura de código (sig), estaba en esta línea:

```
$dato = current($turnosFiltrados);
```

ocasionando que solo una coincidencia fuera mostrada, en lugar de las varias que tenia en la base de datos.

La solución ha sido sencillamente recorrer dicho array `$turnosFiltrados` mediante un `foreach` sustituyendo esa línea de este modo:

```
foreach ($turnosFiltrados as $dato) {
```

y cerrándolo antes del final del condicional donde esta dentro.

Es una solución aceptada por el OP después de discutirla y encontrarla en los comentarios.